# Click event on ngfor loop running twice. angular

Tags: angular, events, click, ngfor

I've found an interesting problem that I can't bypass.

I have the follwing *ngFor loop with a click event.

```
<label class="input-group" *ngFor="let status of statuses; trackBy: id"
    (click)="filterByCategory(status.name)">{{ status.name }}
    <span class="chip chip-icon" [attr.data-chip-state]="status.name">
    {{ partners | counter: status.name }}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

the click event fn filterByCategory() is a simple process, responsible for add or remove string from an array to then filter an array of objects.

```
  filterByCategory(category, event: Event) { 
    let verify = this.filterArr.includes(category);
   
    if (!verify) { 
      this.filterArr.push(category)
    } else {    
      let indexOfCategory = this.filterArr.indexOf(category);
      this.filterArr.splice(indexOfCategory, 1);
    } 
  
    this.filteredPartners = this.partners.filter(partner => {
      return this.filterArr.includes(partner.partner_status.name);
    }) 
  }
```

When the event is fired, it runs twice and the if statement first adds the string and then removes it.

[image]

Does any one has a way to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you attached `click` event listener to `label`. If you click on the label you trigger the event for the first time, but then the checkbox is being clicked and it triggers once again `click` event.

Because you are using `label` here - you can freely move `click` listener to `checkox`. So instead of what you have, you can do it like this:

```
<label class="input-group" *ngFor="let status of statuses; trackBy: id">{{ status.name }}
<span class="chip chip-icon" [attr.data-chip-state]="status.name">
{{ partners | counter: status.name }}</span>
<input type="checkbox" (click)="filterByCategory(status.name)" />
<span class="checkmark"></span>
```

Comment: You were absolutely right! Actually that part didn't cross my mind since the input is display:none, i forgot that the label is asking angular to run the even twice since the check changed! Thank you Kamlar!